# Docpad Run SASS Error

Tags: docpad

I just installed the latest docpad. Installed sass plugin, and I've been getting this error when I used the 'run' command. I'm pretty novice with node and docpad so I'm not really sure whats going on. Anybody have this problem lately?

```
info: Welcome to DocPad v6.64.2 (local installation: /Users/zachfrank/Desktop/mm-t/node_modules/docpad)
info: Contribute: http://docpad.org/docs/contribute
info: Plugins: eco, livereload, sass
info: Environment: development
info: DocPad listening to http://0.0.0.0:9778/ on directory /Users/zachfrank/Desktop/mm-t/out
info: LiveReload listening to new socket on channel /docpad-livereload
info: Generating...
warning: Something went wrong while rendering: styles/app.css.scss
exited with a non-zero status code
error: Something went wrong with the action
error: An error occured: 
Error: exited with a non-zero status code
  at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/zachfrank/Desktop/mm-t/node_modules/docpad-plugin-  sass/node_modules/safeps/out/lib/safeps.js:165:23)
  at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
  at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
  at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
  at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
  at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)

info: Shutting down... cya next time!
```

Here's my 'gem list' if maybe I have a conflicting version of sass or something..

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bourbon (4.0.0)
bundler (1.6.2)
chunky_png (1.3.0)
compass (0.12.6)
foundation (1.0.4)
fssm (0.2.10)
neat (1.6.0)
sass (3.3.5, 3.2.19)
thor (0.19.1)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try copy-pasting your app.css.scss to http://sassmeister.com/ and see if it gives a better error message.

Comment: @Here. Did you try to change .css.scss to .css.sass and please change code for app.css.scss follow sass format.
Or you can try to find with docpad render scss file to css